# Can I separate `.hg` from working directory?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I would like to put directory `C:\WorkDir` under Mercurial version control, but have the repository located somewhere else than `C:\WorkDir\.hg` perhaps `D:\Repositories\WorkDir.hg`. Is that possible in Mercurial?

Comment: Why would you like to do that?

Comment: Perhaps my `C:` drive does not have enough space. Maybe `D:` drive is scheduled for regular backups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer on the Mercurial mailing list by Martin Geisler](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/Newb-question-placing-hg-on-network-td4005967.html) is quite clear about it:

> You cannot move the .hg folder outside of where your working files 
>   reside. That is by definition: the "working copy" *is* the parent 
>   directory of the .hg folder. So if you want to version files in
>
> C:\inetpub\laravel\app
>
> you must have
>
> C:\inetpub\laravel\app\.hg

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid having the drive with the "real" working copy filled up with the repository data, you can use the share extension: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShareExtension .

E.g. if you want to version control `C:\WorkingDir`, but want the big repository data to reside on `D:\Repositories\WorkDir`, just do the following:

1. `cd D:\Repositories`
2. `hg init WorkDir`
3. `cd C:\`
4. `hg share D:\Repositories\WorkDir WorkingDir`

You will still have a `.hg` directory on `C:`, but it will remain really small (around 1MB), while the repo on `D:` will be the one that grows with time.

Comment: Thanks. I may try to use this too. However I am a bit scared of "General caveats" section as I am not sure if any of those can apply to me in the future.

Comment: Well, the caveats are only logical: your shared working directory will immediately influence the "real" repository. So if you use the "real" repository with a working copy, too, any history-rewriting in the shared work-dir may invalidate your repository's work-dir. If you just use it like described in the example above, you'll be fine. I'm using shared repositories almost everyday, and I never lost something due to it. Just keep in mind that it is no clone, but a share!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a `Junction`?

Let's say your repo is `c:\test\.hg` but you want to put `.hg` directory in `c:\shadow`

```
 mkdir c:\shadow
 mv c:\test\.hg c:\shadow\.hg
 mklink /j c:\test\.hg c:\shadow\.hg
```